# Filezilla FTP server is not responding to connections outside the local machine

Tags: networking, ftp, filezilla

I am using filezilla FTP server on my windows 7 PC, and I have tried to connect to the server locally from the CMD and filezilla client, and it is connected normally (show Welcome message and enter user/password ...)

But when I try to connect to the server from other PC, it hangs ,and when I traced it with WireShark I found that there is only one TCP message coming from the other side to establish TCP connection but filezilla server is not responding to it! even If I tried to change the port that filezilla is listening to, the same is happening (even after using netcat to connect to port 21, no response), it is just responding for packets comming from the same machine.

And I have checked that it is listening to port 21, using `netstat -aon`.

NOTE: I have tried other ftp server applications like wing FTP server, and it worked with no problems.

Comment: Did you adjust Windows' firewall to allow FTP?

Comment: Dear, I had tried another FTP server and it worked, should I still have to check windows firewall to allow FTP? //also I have tried to change the port that filezilla server is listening to, and it didn't worked.

Comment: fillezilla client on other PC?

Comment: It's working because I've try it to connect other servers many times.

Answer (score 1):

You must manually add "FileZilla Server.exe" to Windows Firewall's list of allowed applications.
Other FTP servers work because they do this automatically, FileZilla does not.